# Deconstructing WPF's Geometry Object

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to get at the internal structure of a `Geometry` instance from WPF?

I need to convert a string of user-entered Geometry Data, such as

> M10,100 C10,300 300,-200 300,100 Z

in to separate Geometry commands (Move, Cubic Bezier Curve, Close).  I found the [`Geometry.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.parse) method that can convert the string in to an actual `Geometry` instance, but there doesn't seem to be any way to access the details of the structure programatically that I can find.

I was in the process of manually parsing the data when I stumbled across `Geometry.Parse`, and I can continue that if there is no better way, but if there is already a way to do this in the framework, I would obviously prefer it.

---

The reason I need this, is that I am writing a simple geometry data editor.  I have everything working to generate the path data string, but would like to allow the user to import a string in to my application.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var pathFigures = PathFigureCollection.Parse("M10,100 C10,300 300,-200 300,100 Z");
```

You can enumerate the [`PathFigure` objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathfigure(v=vs.110).aspx) in `pathFigures`. Each has a [`StartPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathfigure.startpoint(v=vs.110).aspx) and a [`Segments` collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathfigure.segments(v=vs.110).aspx). `Segments` can be [`ArcSegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment(v=vs.110).aspx), [`LineSegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.linesegment(v=vs.110).aspx), [`BezierSegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.beziersegment(v=vs.110).aspx) etc. All the [Path Markup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx) stuff.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I knew it would come in handy someday. I wrote a path editor too, that's how I came across this.